# "react-native-firebase/messaging" Issues I encountered when upgrading from 11.2.0 to 18.0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I'm making push notifications that can support android 12 or higher. "react-native-firebase/messaging" Issues I encountered when upgrading from 11.2.0 to 18.0.0
The project package.json is as follows:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "18.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "18.0.0",
```

Podfile is as follows:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform:ios, '10.0'

target 'Smart' do
   config = use_native_modules!

   use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

   pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

   target 'SmartTests' do
     inherit! :complete
     # Pods for testing
   end

   # Enables Flipper.
   #
   # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
   # you should disable these next few lines.
   # use_flipper!
   # post_install do |installer|
   # flipper_post_install(installer)
   # end
end

target 'Smart-tvOS' do
   #Pods for SmartHealthUp-tvOS

   target 'Smart-tvOSTests' do
     inherit! :search_paths
     # Pods for testing
   end
end
# Override Firebase SDK Version
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '7.9.0'
```

There is no problem with the Android upgrade, but there is a "pod install" execution problem with iOS:
1.CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RNFBApp"

→Solution: `platform: ios, '10.0'` increased to `platform: ios, '13.0'`

2.CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCoreExtension"

→Solution: `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '7.9.0'` increased to `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.10.0'`

3.The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

→Solution: Added `use_modular_headers!`

and XCode compilation issues:

1."/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp:2285:9 Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operandsCast one or both operands to int to silence this warning"

→Solution: Use the fix prompted by XCode to solve it.

2."/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/RCTBridge.h:24:1 Unknown type name 'RCT_EXTERN'in file included from"

→Solution: Append the following code to Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
     flipper_post_install(installer)
     # NOTE: Change IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 12.4.
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
         #Close Enable Modules (Translation:Close Enable Modules)
         config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'NO'
       end
     end
     # __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end
```

3."/node_modules/react-native-device-info/ios/RNDeviceInfo/DeviceUID.m:7:1 Use of '@import' when modules are disabled"

→Solution:

→1.Enable the modules. Go to the Target > Build Settings and set the Enable Modules (C and Objective-C modules) to YES.

→2.Go to build phases -> Compile Sources -> Select the file -> Add compiler flag -fmodules

4."/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRHeartbeatLogger.m:26:8 Receiver type 'FIRHeartbeatsPayload' for instance message is a forward "

Tried `"rm -rf node_modules & rm -rf yarn.lock & yarn install & cd ios & rm -rf Pods & rm -rf Podfile.lock & pod install"`
I'm very distressed because I couldn't solve the problem. I suspect it's caused by version mismatch. Do you have any good suggestions?